# CSS centring of logo in header

Tags: css, wordpress, graphical-logo

I am struggling to get the header logo on http://inksharks.com centered in most desktop browsers. It does center when scaled to a mobile or tablet view. I have tried several things this was the closest I got to fixing it but it altered my footer as well.

```
.wrap-inner .twelve.pane {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    width: 930px;
}
```

Comment: Your logo and .twelve.pane is floated, remove the floats!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `.logo, h1.logo` remove `float: left;`. Then on `.logo img, .logo .text-logo, .logo .description` put

**CSS:**

```
.logo img, .logo .text-logo, .logo .description{
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1 class="logo img-only">

</h1>
```

add an align attribute to this, and it will look like

```
<h1 class="logo img-only" align="center">

</h1>
```

It will work fine

Comment: According to this http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html align attribute is deprecated in HTML 4.01.

Answer (score 0):

This will center align your logo:

```
h1.logo {
    float: none;
}
div.wrap-inner {
    text-align: center;
}
```

I am overriding the `float: left` on your `h1.logo`, it's better to remove it though if you can.

Also remove `padding-top:44px` from `.nav-right .navigation-wrap` to fix the space between the logo and your content.